# Match string in mysql

Tags: mysql, keyword

I am trying to fetch data from table using a column that contains part of string

Table search_data:

```
id      data

 1      news   
 2      today     
 3      latest
```

when i use the keyword 'news'

```
 select * from search_data where data like '%news%'
```

it is fetching result. but when i use keyword 'latest news'

```
select * from search_data where data like '%latest news%'
```

its not working its showing a empty result set.

can someone help me with the query.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a `FULLTEXT` index so that you can use [MATCH AGAINST](http://dev.mysql.com/doc//refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html) :

```
select 
  * 
from 
  search_data 
where 
  match(data) against ('latest news' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

This would be the most efficient way, you can read more [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc//refman/5.5/en/fulltext-boolean.html)

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're looking for the complete string 'latest news' with text either side of it.  You will need to do `where data like '%news%' or data like '%latest%'` to achieve a search for both keywords where they are not contained on the same row

Comment: it is like this - user will enter key words, he might enter 1 or multiple keywords example: 'latest news today' or 'latest news today in USA' so keywords count is not limited. so i have to search accordingly.

Comment: @Stephan's answer is what I'd use based on your requirement

Answer (score 0):

I do not know what you mean,but I guess you want to do something liek this
select * from search_data where data like '%latest%' OR data like '%news%'

Comment: it is like this - user will enter key words, he might enter 1 or multiple keywords example: 'latest news today' or 'latest news today in USA' , keywords count is not limited. so i have to search accordingly

Comment: oh,if like this,you can explode what the user insert,then make a query yourself.I don't know what language you use.In PHP,we can do something like this.use function exploer($userinput),then you will get an array,then you can foreach() to make a SQL.but for this,I really don't think use sql to query is good idear any more.I will think about:SOLR to to this,I think it will be much faster if you have huge data.

Answer (score 0):

select * from search_data where data like '%latest news%' in this query you mention latest news which means the result must contain "latest news" in string as in your data set it is not present how ever latest and news seprately presents you can use "or" and "and" operator in your query